# Scala: How to use map instead of isEmpty and if

Tags: scala

Newbie Scala question.
I have the following code:

```
val mathsResult = mathsFunction
val comments = Seq(a, b, c).flatten 
CalculationResult(mathsResult, if (comments.isEmpty) None else Some(comments.mkString("\n")))
```

Someone said I could use `map` for the last line, but I've tried a few ways and couldn't get it to work. `CalculationResult` expects an `Option[String]`.

Comment: I don't know about `map`, but you could do something like `Option(comments.mkString("\n")).filter(_.nonEmpty)`

Answer (score 3):

You can say

```
Some(comments).filterNot(_.isEmpty).map(_.mkString("\n"));
// Some(comments)        -- Some(comments)
// filterNot(_.isEmpty)  -- if(comments.isEmpty) None else Some(comments)
// map(_.mkString("\n")) -- if(comments.isEmpty) None else Some(comments.mkString("\n"))
// except comments is only evaluated once
```

You can also do a fold:

```
comments.foldLeft(None: Option[String]) {
  case (Some(acc), elem) => Some(s"$acc\n$elem");
  case (_, elem) => Some(elem)
}
```

but it's not as concise as the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can incorporate the `mkString` functionality into the `reduceOption` partial function argument.

```
val comments: Seq[String] = Seq()  // no comments
comments.reduceOption(_+"\n"+_)    // mkString
// res0: Option[String] = None

val comments: Seq[String] = Seq("a", "b", "c")  // 3 comments
comments.reduceOption(_+"\n"+_)                 // mkString
// res1: Option[String] = Some(a
// b
// c)
```